# Why I cannot install prettytable in Anaconda?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, prettytable

Our homework requires us to install prettytable, but I tried many times and failed to install.

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I used following ways:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
```

Error:

```
No module named 'prettytable'
```

import prettytable

I even downloaded it from online.

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
```

Error:

```
No module named 'prettytable'
```

And:

```
import prettytable
```

Error:

```
No module named 'prettytable'
```

Comment: What have you done to *install* prettytable?

Comment: I used codes:from prettytable import PrettyTable or pip install prettytable

Comment: Did you read this? https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/prettytable

Comment: Yes! I used all of them in Jupyter, but still failed. I just wonder that I should not use it in Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> No module named 'prettytable'

means the module is not installed for your Python. You can only import a module that's installed. A module can be installed by Python default (that's called built-in modules), or explicitly by yourself, or when you install another module.

To install prettytable for your conda environment,

run `conda install -c conda-forge prettytable` from your terminal (command line). Then you will see a bunch of command line instructions. Read carefully, and hit 'y' when you are asked to proceed. If the installation is successful, the process will end with some lines like

> Downloading and Extracting Packages
>
> prettytable-0.7.2    | 14 KB     | ##################################### | 100%
>
> Preparing transaction: done
>
> Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: done

Then you open python (or Jupyter or whatever you use to run python) and try `import prettytable` again.

Comment: It is said: Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> conda install -c conda-forge prettytable
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    conda install -c conda-forge prettytable
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: Your Start menu > type "anaconda prompt" > open the application > type `conda install -c conda-forge prettytable`

Comment: Which command line? I used Python 3 Python Command Line, is that right?

Comment: Anaconda Prompt

Comment: It said: 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then your anaconda is broken. Re-install it.